# clicking a href does not work second time

Tags: html, href

I write 2 examples. at 1st example I can click a lot of time. But at 2nd example clicking does not work at second time . I mean clicking only possible 1 time.

```
<a href="index.php">Click me</a>
<a href="index.php?location=#menu">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Please define "does not work." How is the `location` parameter processed?

Comment: It looks to me that you have inserted a hash (`#`) by mistake.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42653387/4251431 here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the browser's behavior. When a browser sees a hashtag fragment at the end of the URL for the page it's currently on, it attempts to go to that place in the document rather than reloading the page again. It should jump to whatever element has the ID "menu" on it, or do nothing if that element is not found.

If the `#menu` part is meant to be the *value* of your location variable int he query string, you need to escape the hashtag so it is not treated as the fragment. Otherwise, your location variable is being set to empty and the entire `#menu` is being treated as the fragment.

```
<a href="index.php?location=%23menu">Click me</a>
```

In this case, however, I would recommend excluding the hashtag (`#`) from your values to avoid confusion.