# <a href="#..."> link not working

Tags: html, firefox, href

I am trying to create a set of links to specific sections in the page using the `<a href="#...">` notation, but it doesn't seem to work.  Clicking on the link seems to do nothing and `right-click -> open in a new tab` changes the url but does not move to a different section of the page.  I am using Firefox 28.0.  My links are as follows:

```
<div>
    <p>Contents</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="#timing">Timing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#timingdetails">Timing Details</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And they should be linking to:

```
<div id="map">[content]</div>
<div id="timing">[content]</div>
<div id="timingdetails">[content]</div>
```

Links to external webpages work fine.  Placing the `id="..."` feature inside an `<a>` tag instead did not fix the problem.  My webpage url is of the form `http://127.0.0.1/foo/bar/baz/`.  This is within a Python Django project.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/peqase/1/edit?html,css,output — I can't reproduce the problem in Chrome 55 or Firefox 50.

Answer (score 9):

Every `href` needs a corresponding **anchor**, whose **name** or **id** attribute must match the `href` (without the `#` sign).  E.g.,

```
<a href="#map">Map</a>

<a name="map">[content]</a>
```

An enclosing `div` is not necessary, if not used for other purposes.

Comment: Even HTML 4.01 already allowed elements with an `id` to be used as anchor targets, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: for me this is working fine on android, but not on iphone6 safai, can somebody help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124950/does-the-hash-navigation-on-iphone-works-properly

Comment: My mistake was that I added "#" to the id aswell. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 8):

Wow, thanks for pointing that out OP. Apparently Mozilla Firefox doesn't associate the `id` attribute with a location in the HTML Document for elements other than `<a>` but uses the `name` attribute instead, and Google Chrome does exactly the opposite. The most cross-browser proof solution would be to either:

**1.Give your anchor `divs` both a `name` and an `id` to ensure max. browser compatibility, like:**

```
<a href="#map">Go to Map</a> <!-- Link -->
----
<div id="map" name="map"></div> <!-- actual anchor -->
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/feqeh/3/edit

**2.Only use `<a>` tags with the `name` attribute as anchors.**

This will allow the on-page links to work in all browsers.

Comment: for me this is working fine on android, but not on iphone6 safai, can somebody help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124950/does-the-hash-navigation-on-iphone-works-properly

Comment: using both an ID and Name attribute is what made it work for me. An ID on its own did not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

what happened with me is that the href `does not work` `second time` and that because I should `Remove hash` value first,,

take look how I resolved it

```
<a href="#1" onclick="resetHref();">go to Content 1</a>

function resetHref() {
    location.hash = '';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just resurrecting this post because I had a similar problem and the reason was something else.

In my case it was because we had:

```
<base href="http://mywebsite.com/">
```

defined on the .

Obviously, don't just remove it, because you need it if you are using relative paths.

Read more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 3):

Today being **March of 2022**, I had a specific occurrence of this problem that illustrates how the whole web environment is an "issue" today.

Same requirement: links that go to a section of the page.
It worked on my desktop's Chrome and Firefox, but not on my client's and neither on my Android's Chrome.

After reading multiple threads several times for a few hours, I found out that, in order for this behavior to be the most consistent across **browsers** and **browser versions**, you have to implement both things:

- a container with an `id`, and
- an `anchor` with a `name` property,

The most important part is that the `anchor` tag with a `name`, **must have content inside of it**.

So, you have your links

```
<a href="#page-section">Go to section</a>
<!-- more links -->
```

And you have the sections you want your links to go to

```
<div id="page-section">
    <a name="page-section" class="collapse"> placeholder-content (important) </a>
    <!-- your section content -->
</div>
```

Since you MUST have content inside the `anchor` with the `name`, you can then hide it in several ways.
My approach was to just set it's height to 0.
In order for the height to be effective, the `anchor` tag's `display` property should be set to `block` or `inline-block` for example.

```
.collapse {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

Finally it all worked, and I have to thank the many developers who struggle with this sort of thing (which should be much easier to do, but, the web...), and all the people who answer questions like this and share their knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much. i was facing this strange issue and dont know what i was doing wrong. It works well on my pc but in my clients machine it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#1">Content 1</a>    
<a href="#2">Content 2</a> 
<a href="#3">Content 3</a>
....
<a name="1"></a>Text here for content 1
<a name="2"></a>Text here for content 2
<a name="3"></a>Text here for content 3
```

When clicking on "Content 1" it will take directly to "Text here for Content 1.
Guaranteed!

Comment: Very very bad example & practice to use numbers as any name/id/class values.

Comment: Also, I tested this example on Google Chrome and it only works when your targets are `<a>`'s. Btw thanks for voting down my completely valid & tested answer.

Comment: for me this is working fine on android, but not on iphone6 safai, can somebody help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124950/does-the-hash-navigation-on-iphone-works-properly

Answer (score 0):

This might help

JS:

```
function goto($hashtag){
     document.location = "index.html#" + $hashtag;
}
```

HTML :

```
<li><a onclick="goto('aboutus')">ABOUT</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case The input tag was the problem. I implemented my tabs by input (radio buttons) which was preventing the anchor tag's behaviour.

It was like this at first (not working):

```
<a href="#name">
  <li>
    <label></label>
    <input></input>
  </li>
</a>
```

Then I removed the input tag and it worked:

```
<a href="#name">
  <li>
    <label></label>
    // <input></input> <!-- removed it -->
  </li>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using preventDefault in javascript

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Here is something that I finally got to work in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Around any text create an anchor tag like this:

```
<a class="anchor" id="X" name="X">text</a>
```

Set "X" to whatever you want.

You must enclose something in the anchor tags such as text or an image. It will NOT work without these.

For the link, use this:

```
<a href="#X">text</a>
```

As for getting rid of the CSS for links using our anchor tag use something like this:

```
a.anchor {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

This seems to work well.

Comment: You didn't say anything new from the original question. And it seems the question problem cannot be reproduced any more. So this is not a real answer.